# Trying to get User posts to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am following Hartl tutorial mostly right now but I wanted to make it so that a user can just make a post, that post will then belong to him and show it in a simple way on a seperate page for instance. No twitter like stuff.

```
def create
      @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Post created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'posts/index'
    end
  end
```

Now I have this in my post_controller. I have form that posts to @post when submitted. But I dont get the flash message which means the post was not saved even when I pressed submit.
Why is  that first of all and secondly, I dont really get the code line too : `@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)`. What is that build supposed to do exactly? Am I not supposed to just do a `Post.new(post_params)?` And modify it a bit so that the post would also belong to a user?

I made a gist of my user and post model: https://gist.github.com/Veske/7988593

Server log:

```
Started POST "/posts/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-16 17:19:52 +0200
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iT08NreZv83WtImK6V9/jXZOpgtzwSLjlxB7T/wn0E4=", "text"=>"This is a s
 post!", "commit"=>"Submit!"}
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '390d667f7603eee5976fd8500a9a8776c
d3' LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 19.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

This is my form

```
<%= form_tag(@post) do %>
    <div class="forms">
    <%= text_area_tag(:content, nil, placeholder: "Type text in here...")%>
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit!' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Build is correct..it's created a new micropost for the current user. Please posts your user model & post model...make sure user_id:integer is a column in your microposts db table

Comment: If you had posted your trace, i.e. if there are errors then it would have been simpler to spot the problem. Just to confirm, are your `user` and `post` models are related by `user has_many posts` and `post belongs_to user`?

Comment: Yes, I made a gist and edited original post, all the models are there.

Comment: And you have your Session's Helper to define the current_user?

Comment: Yes, sessions helper is done also.

Comment: Alright, re-submit the form and tell us what the error log says the problem is. You can easily check for errors in your Command Line where you started the rails server. Cuz we can keep guessing but if we know where the error comes from it can easily be solved

Comment: Posted the log to original post. To me it seems that it did not even try to create a new entry into database? It just posts and does nothing after that?

Comment: This could be wrong, but it's worth of shot. In the form tag instead of `form_tag` try `form_for`

Comment: If I do that I get the First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty error

Comment: Allright, I changed it to   <%= form_for(posts_create_path) do %> no errors but the text is still not saved into database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer. I made a gist https://gist.github.com/licatajustin/7989891

For next time, you can easily check by testing through your Command Line.

In your console, type in

```
rails c

> u = User.first
> u.posts.create(content: "My first post")
```

and see if that works

Comment: => #<Post id: nil, content: "Second post", user_id: 4, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):005:0>

Comment: So it does create it via CLI but not in my App.

Comment: Seems it works like that
But why did the build not work?

Answer (score 1):

You're sending text = "This is a s post!"
But your model suggests that the attribute 'content' is required (not 'text')

Therefore @post.save is failing and you're falling into the failed statement. I'd suggest you need to look at the form that creates this post as it doesn't seem to be creating the correct attributes.

Comment: Updates original post with my form. I tried to use form_tag(posts_create_path) at first but it did not work like that for some reason.